# Display Heading Differently on Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I apologize for the vague title, but my issue is fairly specific. I'm currently converting our site to use Bootstrap, and I've come across a small thing that bugs me with the header (jumbotron). When viewed on mobile, or with a xsmall/small screen size, the words "Service" and "Agency" will force down to the next line and display underneath our tree logo (shown in pictures)

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I cannot just simply split the tree logo and words into two different columns, as this forces them to appear on opposite ends of the screen when viewed on desktop.

[Small Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O78nb.png)

[XSmall Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iDZM.png)

[Desktop Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wl14.png)

Instead, I'd like for the words "Human", "Service", and "Agency" all to display stacked on top of one another, next to the tree, when viewed on small or xsmall screens. Any ideas on how to approach this?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HSA - Community Support Provider</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="We offer case management, psychiatric care, counseling to people with mental illness and additctions, and services for people with developmental disabilities." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="counselor, mental illness, disabilities, Watertown, SD, psychiatrist, counseling, mental health, addiction, services, developmentally disabled, detoxification, half-way house" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/hsa.ico" type="image/hsa-icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            h4 {
                font-size: 18px !important;
            }
            
            @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
                #heading_title {
                    display: inline-block;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron text-left" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:0;margin-bottom:0;background-color:white">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1 id="heading">
                        <img src="images/HSA-tree-logo.gif" alt="HSA's Tree Logo"/>
                        <span id="heading_title">Human Service Agency</span>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="mhstaff.html">Counselors</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="jobs.html">Career Opportunities</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="foundation.html">Foundation/Donations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="bod.html">Board of Directors</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About/Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="justify-content-center" style="background-color:#f8f9fa;color:#7c7c7d;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <p id="addressbar">123 19th Street NE, Watertown, SD (605) 886-0123</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="deptcards">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div class="deptcard">
                        <a href="addictions.html" title="Addiction Services" accesskey="A" target="_self">
                            <div align="center"><img class="deptimg" src="images/group_counseling.jpg" alt="Group Counseling">
                                <div class="deptcontainerone"></div>
                                <p><b>Addictions</b></p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div class="deptcard">
                        <a href="mh.html" title="Mental Health Services" accesskey="M" target="_self">
                            <div align="center"><img class="deptimg" src="images/mh.jpg" alt="Mental Health" >
                                <div class="deptcontainertwo"></div>
                                <p><b>Behavioral Health</b></p> 
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div class="deptcard">
                        <a href="serenityhills.html" title="Serenity Hills" accesskey="S" target="_self">
                            <div align="center"><img class="deptimg" src="images/serenity_hills.jpg" alt="Serenity Hills" >
                                <div class="deptcontainerthree"></div>
                                <p><b>Serenity Hills</b></p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div class="deptcard">
                        <a href="nh.html" title="New Horizons" accesskey="N" target="_self">
                            <div align="center"><img class="deptimg" src="images/new_horizons.jpg" alt="New Horizons">
                                <div class="deptcontainerfour"></div>
                                <p><b>New Horizons</b></p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div class="deptcard">
                        <a href="Employment Services/index.html" title="Employment Services" accesskey="E" target="_self">
                            <div align="center"><img class="deptimg" src="images/employment_connections.jpg" alt="Employment Connections" >
                                <div class="deptcontainerfive"></div>
                                <p><b>Job Services</b></p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div class="deptcard">
                        <a href="care.html" title="CARE" accesskey="C" target="_self">
                            <div align="center"><img class="deptimg" src="images/care.jpg" alt="C.A.R.E." >
                                <div class="deptcontainersix"></div>
                                <p><b>C.A.R.E.</b></p> 
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="layoutdimsend"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12" id="columnside">
                    <h3 align="center">Links</h3>
                    <p align="center"><a href="http://www.humanserviceagency.org/NEPrevention/index.php" target="_blank"><img src="images/neprc_logo_sm.jpg" alt="NEPRC"/></a></p>
                    <p align="center"><a href="http://www.humanserviceagency.org/WHY/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/why_logo_sm.jpg" alt="WHY" /></a></p>
                    <p align="center"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/humanserviceagency" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook_link.jpg" alt="Facebook Link"/></a></p>
                    <p align="center"><a href="images/umbrella.pdf" target="_blank"><h2 align="center"><img src="images/umbrella.jpg" alt="Umbrella Newsletter Link"/></h2></a></p>
                    <div class="stylegray">
                        <p align="center"><a href="https://namisouthdakota.org/local-affiliates/nami-watertown/" target="_blank"><img src="images/nami.jpg" alt="NAMI SD Link"/></a></p>
                            <div align="center">
                                <img class="columnimage" src="images/amazon_smile.jpg" alt="Amazon Smile" />
                            </div>
                        <p align="center" class="stylegray">Sign up at <a href="https://smile.amazon.com/ch/46-0275247" target="_top">smile.amazon.com</a></p>
                        <p class="stylenorm">Amazon will donate 0.5% of the price of your eligible AmazonSmile purchases to the Human Service Agency if you have signed up to participate.  AmazonSmile is the same as Amazon. Same products, prices, and service.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12" id="columnmid">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <h1>Remembrance Ceremony</h1>
                                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/kxXfHuuJQJg" frameborder="0" alt="Slide 1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                    <p>Glacial Lakes SAFE (Suicide Awareness for Everyone) hosted their 6th annual Remembrance Ceremony on September 2, 2020.  With the assistance of Prairie Lakes Healthcare System, SAFE was able to host this year's event virtually.  September is Suicide Awareness month, and we are encouraging those who have lost a loved one to suicide to do something to honor them and to help raise awareness of the impact of suicide.  We want you to know that there is HOPE; there is healing; and there are many resources and services available to help 24/7.  You are not alone.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <h1>Stakeholders Give HSA High Marks</h1>
                                    <img src="images\stakeholders.png" style="width:100%" alt="Slide 2">
                                    <p>A recent stakeholder survey of HSA gave high ratings to the agency across the board. A few of the comments made included, "Our community is a better place because of the fine men and women of HSA!", "HSA is a community leader in promoting holistic health," "Clients attending treatment state the services offered are informative, they are challenged to invest themselves in the provided treatment,"  "There is a strong partnership between HSA and Law Enforcement.  Every referral I have ever made was met with nothing but professional courtesy," "The on call service is available day or night," and "HSA is very accommodating to the needs of our high school students."</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <h1>Employment Connections/Employment Services</h1>
                                    <img src="images\landscaping.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Slide 3">
                                    <p>Pictured: Anthony Kinsinger enjoys his new positon with Professional Landscaping.  Anthony is the inventory/plant caretaker and takes care of animals on the property. Community Services helps people find jobs in the community. They work closely with the local Vocational Rehabilitation office and businesses in town.  New Horizons also provides Project Skills, a job program for students with disabilities. New Horizons also provides job class for students. We have so many success stories and examples of the benefits available to employers when they hire people with disabilities. <a href="Employment Services/index.html" target="_self">Read more about it on our employment services page.</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <h1>HSA Foundation: Making Dreams Come True</h1>
                                    <img src="images\mt_olympus.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Slide 4">
                                    <p>The Human Service Agency Foundation raises money and accepts donations to help with special projects for people served. This summer Sandy Tierney was able to go to Wisconsin with the help of ‘Making Dreams Come True’and funding from the HSA Foundation. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12" id="columnside">
                    <h3 align="center">Resources</h3>
                    <p><h4>Crisis line:</h4></p>
                    <div class = "stylenorm" align="left">
                        <p>Call 605-886-0123 <strong>24 Hours/Day</strong></p>
                        <p>In Sisseton, call 605-698-7688</p>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Counseling Appointments<br /> and Addiction Services:</h4>
                    <div class = "stylenorm" align="left">
                        <p>Call 605-886-0123</p>
                        <p>Monday-Thursday 8 AM-8 PM, Fridays 8 AM-5PM</p>
                        <p>In Sisseton, call 605-698-7688</p>
                        <p>In Milbank, call 605-886-0123</p>
                    </div>
                    <h4><a href="twelvestep.html" title="Alcoholics Anonymous Meetings" target="_blank">Alcoholics Anonymous Meetings</a></h4>  
                    <h4><a href="http://www.humanserviceagency.org/library/index.php" target="_self">Prevention Resource Library</a></h4>
                    <h4><a href="images\familyresourcedirectory.pdf" target="_blank">Watertown Family Resource Directory</a></h4>
                    <h4><a href="WHY\familyresourcedir.html" target="_blank">Watertown Family Resource Directory - Online</a></h4>
                    <h4><a href="http://www.watertowncommunityfoundation.com" target="_self">Watertown Community Foundation</a></h4>
                    <p align="left" class="stylenorm"><a href="serenityhills.html" target="_self">Apply to Serenity Hills</a></p>
                    <p align="left" class="stylenorm"><a href="Employment Services/index.html" target="_self">Hire People with Disabilities</a></p>
                    <p align="left" class="stylenorm"><a href="care.html" target="_self">Request CARE/NE Payee Services</a></p>
                    <p align="left" class="stylenorm"><a href="cfcm.html" target="_self">Conflict Free Case Management Services</a></p></br>
                    <h3 align="center">Forms</h3>
                    <p align="left" class="stylenorm"><a href="Forms\ROI.pdf" target="_self">Release of Information</a></p></br>
                    <p align="left" class="stylenorm"><a href="ClientQuestionnaire.html" target="_blank">Intake Questionnaire</a></p>
                    <p align="left" class="stylenorm"><a href="AdultQuestionnaire.html" target="_blank">Adult Questionnaire</a></p>
                    <p align="left" class="stylenorm"><a href="ChildQuestionnaire.html" target="_blank">Child Questionnaire</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p class="footerlinks" text-align="center" ><a class="footerlinks" Href="TermsAndConditions.html">Terms and Conditions</a><a class="footerlinks" href="privacystatement.html">Privacy Statement</a><a  class="footerlinks" href="privacypractices.html">Privacy of Health Information</a></p>
            <p class="footerstyle1" text-align="center"><span class="style5">Human Service Agency is an equal opportunity employer and provider</span></p>
            <p align="center"> <img src="images\united_way.gif" alt="United Way" style="max-height:40px" /> <img src="images\accredited.jpg" alt="Accredited by CQL" style="max-height:40px" /> <img src="images\eho.bmp" alt="Equal Housing Opportunity" style="max-height:40px"/></p>
            <p class="footerstyle6">The  Human Service Agency provides services for anyone seeking assessment, treatment  &amp; aftercare for any substance abuse/dependency. We do not discriminate on the basis of race, color, religion, gender, gender  expression, age, national origin, disability, marital status, sexual  orientation, military status, familial status, or any other classification protected by applicable federal, state or local law. We do prioritize  services for pregnant women or women with dependent children. We also  prioritize treatment for individuals using intravenous drugs as the lethality  of such use is severe and life threatening. <br />We  seek to provide services for these priority groups by publicizing this notice  in our agencies as well as on our website. Pregnant women who also use  intravenous drugs are of highest priority. In the event the individual in any  priority population is waiting for a residential bed in a residential facility  elsewhere, he/she will be allowed participation in HSA Intensive Outpatient  Treatment Program until placement is made. </p>
            <p class="footerstyle6"><span class="footerstyle7">Policy: The Human Service Agency provides safeguards designed to protect the personal information of its personnel and clients. These safeguards include efforts to keep personal information confidential, limits access to only those personnel who need this information, prevents the unlawful disclosure of this information, and effectively disposes of this information in a manner that ensures that it is not retrievable after disposal. The Human Service Agency continually works to comply with all federal and state law regarding the protection of personal information.  Any Human Service Agency staff member who violates this policy may be subject to civil or criminal penalties and the breach of confidentiality could lead to disciplinary action (up to and including termination of employment). Personal Information is defined as: non-public information which is associated with a specfiic individual through one or more identifiers.  Examples include Social Security numbers, drivers' license numbers, credit or debit card numbers and health insurance identification numbers.<br />Copyright &copy; 2017 Human Service Agency</span></p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #003366;
}

a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
    color:#003399;
}

a:visited {
    color: #003399;
}

img {
    margin: 10px 0 5px;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    color: #369;
}

.header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.header ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
}

.header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    right: 50%;
}

.header ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

.header ul li a:hover {
    background:#369;
    color:#fff;
}

.header ul li a.active,
.header ul li a.active:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.header ul li a span {
    display:block;
}

#addressbar{
    clear:both;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #004000;
    margin:0;
    padding:6px 15px !important;
    text-align:center;
}

#layoutdimsend{
    clear:both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top:4px solid #004000;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px 5px !important;
    text-align:center;
}

.deptcard {
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.deptcard:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 12px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.deptimg {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.deptcontainerone {
    margin: 7px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background-color:#008000;
}

.deptcontainertwo {
    margin: 7px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background-color:#003399;
}

.deptcontainerthree {
    margin: 7px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background-color:#1E90FF;
}
.deptcontainerfour {
    margin: 7px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background-color:#800000;
}
.deptcontainerfive {
    margin: 7px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background-color:#800080;
}
.deptcontainersix {
    margin: 7px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background-color:#FF1493;
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    background:#00400;
}

#footer p {
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #004000;
}

.footerstyle1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}

.footerstyle4 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 10;
}

.footerstyle5 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.footerstyle6 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: x-small;
    text-align:center;
}

.footerstyle7 {
    font-size: x-small;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer .footerlinks {
    color: #FFFF99;
    text-align: center;
}

- For the slide show -
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    clear: both;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* Number text (1/3 etc) OR Header*/
.numbertext {
  background-color: rgba(33,66,88,0.8);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 85px;
  width: 100%;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(33,66,88,0.8);
 
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .2} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .2} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
- End for the slide show -.rowtwo 
/*Here we have the options for the side navigation that is off canvas - the complete listing of services   */

/* The drop down button menu */
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color:#666666;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 10px;
    border:thin;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;

}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
 .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 240px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
 .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#000000;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
 .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color:#3e8e41}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;} .columnimage {
    text-align: center;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #3366CC;
    border-right-color: #3366CC;
    border-bottom-color: #3366CC;
    border-left-color: #3366CC;
}
.stylegray {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color:#333333;
}
.stylenorm {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#000000;
}

#columnside {
    background-color: #eee;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.labels {
    font-size: 10px;
}

#heading {
    color: black;
}

.carousel-item {
    background-color: white;
}

ol li {
    color: black;
    background-color; black;
}
```

Comment: On desktop view, is the image on the left and the text on the right? if so you can split them into 2 cols instead of 1

Comment: No, on desktop view I want the words appearing next to the tree logo still, not on opposite ends of the screen.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot for the current desktop view?

Comment: @AhmadTahhan Added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1 id="heading">
        <img src="images/HSA-tree-logo.gif" alt="HSA's Tree Logo"/>
        <span id="heading_title">Human Service Agency</span>
     </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this:

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
          <img src="images/HSA-tree-logo.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="HSA's Tree Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h1 id="heading">       
                <span id="heading_title">Human Service Agency</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it!